# HTML Anchors not working inside divs with overflow:scroll?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I wrapped all contents with `<div>` which height and width is both 100px. Contents inside this `<div>` contains index and content.

The problem is that clicking "a2" in the following code won't let me jump to the bottom contents in Google Chrome.

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a1">a1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a2">a2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="a1">a1</h2>
    a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>
    <h2 id="a1">a2</h2>
    a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>
</div>
```

The working code can be seen from the following link.
http://jsfiddle.net/L7rQ6/

Is there some good solution to make "a2" jump to the proper contents?

Comment: you repeated the same id twice...

Comment: Yeah the id is same a1, thats why its not working. Its working fine with different id http://jsfiddle.net/nucleo1985/L7rQ6/3/

Comment: I've got it... I was so stupid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing to update your 2nd `<h2>` element set `id="a2"` instead of `id="a1"`

Check <kbd>[**demo jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L7rQ6/1/)</kbd>

Update this small,

```
<h2 id="a2">a2</h2>
```

#### HTML (Updated)

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a1">a1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a2">a2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="a1">a1</h2>
           a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>
    <h2 id="a2">a2</h2>
           a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>
</div>
```

Comment: I think no any other answer required here. As @Felix already catch the silly mistake and solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
<h2 id="a2">
```

instead of:

```
<h2 id="a1">
```

for your second `h2` element. Current you've duplicated `id` which is invalid HTML as well.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7rQ6/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

As Felix and user1153551 has said you have duplicated the Id for both of the  tags try this.

```
<div style="height:100px;width:100px;overflow:scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#a1">a1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#a2">a2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="a1">a1</h2>
    a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>a1<br/>
    <h2 id="a2">a2</h2>
    a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>a2<br/>
</div>
```